# can we apply custom directive for angular-google-map

Tags: angular7, angular-google-maps

I'm using angular-google-map.I wanted to add custom directive( other than agm specified directive) to show tooltip on hover of polylines.

I tried applying custom directive but no effects are shown in the map.tooltip for normal html like select,h4 works.
please tell me whether we can apply custom directive or not.if yes then  how.Below is my code

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [scrollwheel]="false" [zoom]="zoom" [styles]='mapStyles'>
        <ng-container>
          <agm-marker-cluster
            imagePath="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/master/markerclustererplus/images/m">
            <agm-marker *ngFor="let m of markers; let i = index" (markerClick)="clickedMarker(m.label, i)"
              [latitude]="m.lat" [longitude]="m.lng" [label]="{color: 'white', text: m.title}"
              [markerDraggable]="m.draggable" [iconUrl]="m.icon" (dragEnd)="markerDragEnd(m, $event)">
            </agm-marker>
          </agm-marker-cluster>
          <agm-polyline (lineMouseOver)="clickedLine(i,polyline.data)" *ngFor="let polyline of polylines;let i = index;"
            [strokeColor]="polyline.color" tooltip="this is is tooltip" >
            <agm-polyline-point *ngFor="let point of polyline.path" [latitude]="point.latitude"
              [longitude]="point.longitude">
            </agm-polyline-point>
          </agm-polyline>
        </ng-container>
      </agm-map>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, because `agm-polyline` is not a component, it's a directive, even though it looks like an html element. This means that there is no host to bind the directive to.